# Anuglar2- model data jumps

Tags: javascript, html, angular, multidimensional-array

I'm making a Anuglar2 application for people to log how many hours they put into each course, assignments, etc., per week (though there we be more advance options later on). 
Right now i have a table which lists out how many hours you spent on each course per day. I want the user to be able to just edit and change any values as he/she goes along. So i have a two dimensional array ( named data), and i attach models to each element in the array, which i then represent as a input element. 
Everything works fine, but there is a weird bug. Whenever you delete the value in the input box and re-enter new data, it jumps to the next input element. I cant figure out why. Anyone got any ideas ?

Example in GIF format (sorry for the quality had to use a converter) 
[image]

[gif link in case you cant see it on Stack](https://media.giphy.com/media/xUA7bctx1o3Fms2VPi/giphy.gif)

home.html

```
<!-- Table -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12">
        <h1 class="page-header">Weekly Status Report</h1>
        <table class="table table-responsive table-stripped table-bordered table-hover" *ngIf="courses">
            <thead>
                <tr class="btn-primary">
                    <th>Course</th>
                    <th>Time</th>
                    <th>SM #</th>
                    <th>Est</th>
                    <th *ngFor="let weekday of week">
                        {{weekday  | date:'EEEE'}}
                    </th>
                    <th>Total</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody *ngFor="let course of courses; let i = index;">
                <tr>
                    <td >
                        {{course.name}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="alert-info">
                    <!-- Account for the title row -->
                    <td>
                        Date
                    </td>
                    <td >
                        Documentation Type
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Documentation Text
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr *ngFor="let content of course.hours" class="alert-warning">
                    <td>
                        {{content.day| date}}
                    </td>
                    <td [attr.colspan]="3">
                        {{ title }} 
                    </td>
                    <td [attr.colspan]="7">

                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="alert-success">
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <th></th>
                    <!-- DATA ARRAY -->
                    <th *ngFor="let d of data[i]; let j = index;">
                        <div>
                            <input maxlength="3" size="3" [(ngModel)]="data[i][j]" />
                        </div>
                    </th>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot class="btn-primary">
                <tr>
                    <td>Report Totals(all courses)</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td *ngFor="let pivot of [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]">
                        {{ getSum(pivot) }}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{getTotal()}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

home.component.ts

```
week: Array<any> = new Array(); 
data: Array<any> = new Array(); 
constructor(private hm: HomeService) {
    let subscription = this.hm.getFormat(this.courses, this.week)
        .subscribe(
            value => {
                this.data.push(value);
            },
            error => {
                console.log(error)
            },
            () => {
                console.log("Formated");

            }
        );  
}
```

home.service.ts

```
getFormat(courses: any, weekdays: any): Observable<any> {
    return new Observable(observer => {
        // For all courses
        courses.forEach(c => {
            // temp week
            let week: Array<any> = new Array();
            // For each weekday 
            weekdays.forEach(w => {
                let found: boolean = false;
                // get hours spent on course 
                c.hours.forEach(h => {
                    let hour:Date = new Date (h.day); 
                    // if the hours spent match up on the day push it to the week array
                    if (w.day.getTime() === hour.getTime()) {
                        week.push(h.duration);
                        found = true
                    }
                });
                // If no time was found on this take, push a empty string. 
                if (!found) {
                    week.push(0);
                }
            });
            // push that week to the component 
            observer.next(week);
        });
        observer.complete();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because of how data is tracked.
When you change the value from the array it will become another value, thus not being able to track it as it will keep track of the older value.

Your case is similar to the following **bad code**:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <table>
        <tr *ngFor="let dim1 of values; let dim1Index = index">
          <td *ngFor="let dim2 of dim1; let dim2Index = index">
            <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="values[dim1Index][dim2Index]" />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {

  values: string[][];

  constructor() {
    this.values = [
      ['a1', 'b1', 'c1'],
      ['a2', 'b2', 'c2'],
      ['a3', 'b3', 'c3']
    ];
  }
}
```

There are multiple solutions:

**Solution 1: Using an object to wrap the value**

Look at the `values` array.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <table>
        <tr *ngFor="let dim1 of values; let dim1Index = index">
          <td *ngFor="let dim2 of dim1; let dim2Index = index">
            <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="values[dim1Index][dim2Index].value" />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <br/>
      {{ values | json }}
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {

  values: string[][];

  constructor() {
    this.values = [
      [{ value: 'a1' }, { value: 'b1' }, { value: 'c1' }],
      [{ value: 'a2' }, { value: 'b2' }, { value: 'c2' }],
      [{ value: 'a3' }, { value: 'b3' }, { value: 'c3' }]
    ];
  }
}
```

**Solution 2: Using a custom trackBy function for *ngFor**

Note that this solution is based on `trackByIndex` function which returns the index of the item, thus the item being located by its index instead of its value.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <table>
        <tr *ngFor="let dim1 of values; let dim1Index = index; trackBy: trackByIndex">
          <td *ngFor="let dim2 of dim1; let dim2Index = index; trackBy: trackByIndex">
            <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="values[dim1Index][dim2Index]" />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <br/>
      {{ values | json }}
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {

  values: string[][];

  constructor() {
    this.values = [
      ['a1', 'b1', 'c1'],
      ['a2', 'b2', 'c2'],
      ['a3', 'b3', 'c3']
    ];
  }

  public trackByIndex(index: number, item) {
    return index;
  }
}
```

Therefore in your code you can use:

`<tbody *ngFor="let course of courses; let i = index; trackBy: trackByIndex">`

next

`<th *ngFor="let d of data[i]; let j = index; trackBy: trackByIndex">`

and finally define `trackByIndex` in your component:

```
  public trackByIndex(index: number, item) {
    return index;
  }
```